# How to run script on startup and shutdown OS X El Capitan

Tags: launchd, macos

Actually I want to make a RAM drive related to [this script](https://github.com/khacpm/RAMDISK-on-boot/blob/master/ramdisk.sh) on my Mac.

Here is what I did:

1. Disabled SIP in recovery mode using command "csrutil"
2. Created a plist file in /Library/LaunchDaemons/
   and entered `launchctl -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/vn.magik.ramdisk.plist`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
       <dict>
           <key>Label</key>
               <string>vn.magik.ramdisk</string>
           <key>ProgramArguments</key>
               <array>
                 <string>/Users/khacpm/ramdisk.sh</string>
               </array>
           <key>RunAtLoad</key>
               <true/>
           <key>StandardOutPath</key>
               <string>/Users/khacpm/ramdisk.log</string>
           <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
               <string>/Users/khacpm/ramdisk.err</string>
       </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
3. Created .sh file and put it in ~/ramdisk.sh

   code:

   ```
   function fstartup()
   {
       //put folder into ramdisk
   }
   function fshutdown()
   {
       //detach ramdisk
   }

   function framdisk()
   {
       //do something
   }
   trap fshutdown SIGTERM
   trap fshutdown SIGKILL
   fstartup;
   ```

The problem is, the function fstartup runs well but it seems like function fshutdown isn't called by the system.

Comment: Have you tried disabling SIP to see if your scripts are even compatible with that new protection?

Comment: I set the nvram rootless=0 already. but it not work

Comment: You can't modify /System with sip. I'll answer how to disable that

Comment: Thanks god, I boot into recovery mode and disable SIP with command "csrutil disable" and now I can modify /System folder. But sadly what I want still not work, the script not run on startup and shutdown

Comment: Many years laster and I'm trying to do the same exact thing with the same exact starting script. I can get both the startup function and shutdown function to run, however the shutdown function which copies the files off the RAM disk will not complete. It seems the RAM disk is destroyed by the system before this very fast `cp` command can finish running. Is there any way to hold up the shutdown for a few seconds?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correction to the shell script should be:

```
function fstartup()
{
    //put folder into ramdisk
     tail -f /dev/null &
     wait $!
}
function fshutdown()
{
    //detach ramdisk

}

function framdisk()
{
    //do something
}
trap fshutdown SIGTERM
trap fshutdown SIGKILL
fstartup;
```

So that it will wait during the startup, not the shutdown.

I'm currently running my version and it appears to work fine, it correctly runs the shutdown function when the computer is shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

I found one bug in my script:
Missing these lines in function fshutdown:

```
tail -f /dev/null &
wait $!
```

the correct function is:

```
function fstartup()
{
    //put folder into ramdisk
}
function fshutdown()
{
    //detach ramdisk
     tail -f /dev/null &
     wait $!
}

function framdisk()
{
    //do something
}
trap fshutdown SIGTERM
trap fshutdown SIGKILL
fstartup;
```

base on [apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html), When the system shuts down, it sends a SIGTERM signal to all of the daemons that it started.
But my old script will execute and close itself after it started.
You need to make your script alive and wait for Sigterm signal by adding some functions like "sleep" or "wait" to make the script alive.

Comment: If the removal of the bug solved your problem, please add an explication whether and why this solved your question in your answer.